# Missing number error with acro after updating and installing packages

Tags: biblatex, errors, latex3, acro

I recently updated `l3kernel` and other packages and installed `biblatex-chem` and `libertinust1math`.  I am now getting an error with the `acro` package.

Specifically, I am trying to use `\emph{\Iac{NFA}}` and am getting "ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero" for `\l__acro_article_Indefinite_bool` in the following minimal example.  (See below for the complete error message.)  Before updating and installing the above packages, everything had been working correctly with the document from which I derived this example.

I'm not sure what's going on, although it seems related to `biblatex` for some reason.  Does anyone know what is causing this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{NFA}{%
  short = NFA,
  short-indefinite = an,
  long = nondeterministic finite automaton,
  long-plural-form = nondeterministic finite automata%
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\emph{\Iac{NFA}} is a mathematical machine.
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\end{document}
```

Here is a section of the `.log` file surrounding the error.  The complete `.log` file can be found at [.log of error](https://pastebin.com/raw/kHKPpvqG)

```
\openout3 = `thesis.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'thesis.bbl' found.

(./thesis.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 16.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 16.
\l__acro_aux_file_iow=\write4
\openout4 = `thesis.acr'.

\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box46

(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-ba
sic-dictionary-english.trsl
File: translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl (english translation file `tra
nslations-basic-dictionary')
)
Package translations Info: loading dictionary `translations-basic-dictionary' f
or `english'. on input line 16.

./thesis.tex:17: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \l__acro_article_Indefinite_bool 
l.17 \emph{\Iac{NFA}}
                      is a mathematical machine.
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 19.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 19.

(./thesis.aux (./thesis.acr))
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 19.
```

Comment: There wasn't any recent (that I recall) breaking change to `l3kernel`, so I find it rather weird.  Could you please try to make a compilable example that reproduces the issue?  Also, run your dissertation with `\listfiles` and show the `.log` output of that, please.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The `.log` is over 5000 lines long and the file list is nearly 200 lines long.  Should I paste here, or...?  I will work on a compilable example that reproduces the error, but I have a custom document class and many packages, so I'm not sure how minimal that example will end up being...

Comment: You can use pastebin.com to send the log (it might help pinpoint the problem).  A compilable example will really help (even if not that minimal): the amount of combinations in a failing LaTeX document are endless, so a starting point is essential, so take your time.

Comment: show the complete error message.Copy it from the log, including the lines around it.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik @UlrikeFischer  I was able to narrow it down to some interaction between `biblatex` (or its dependencies) with `acro`.  The log file is linked in the above edits.  Also, I remembered that I installed `libertinust1math` and `biblatex-chem` just prior to these errors, if that is a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ouch! This is a sneaky one.

First, the issue is unrelated (kind of) to `biblatex`.  The issue only appears there because `biblatex` adds `\NoCaseChange` to `expl3`'s `\text_expand:n`.  If you do that manually with

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_expand_exclude_tl { \NoCaseChange }
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl { \NoCaseChange }
\cs_set_eq:NN \NoCaseChange \use:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

you can remove `biblatex` from the equation.

The problem is that `\NoCaseChange` is equal to `\use:n`, and `\use:n` is an *extremely* ubiquitous macro, so that will make anything *look* like `\NoCaseChange`, which is not good.  In the specific case of `acro`, it uses `\tl_map_tokens:nn` to iterate on a list that contains `{indefinite}`, and eventually reaches a code that looks like:

```
\use:n{\__acro_article:nnn {NFA}{long-acc}}{indefinite}
```

which should pass the `{indefinite}` token list to `\__acro_article:nnn {NFA}{long-acc}`, which works great... unless `\use:n` means to skip the argument while case-changing, which is exactly what happens here: the `\__acro_article:nnn` thing is skipped, and `indefinite` is title-case changed to `Indefinite`, and everything goes off the tracks.

I think the correct way to fix this would be to make `\NoCaseChange` *different* from `\use:n` and `\@firstofone` so that it isn't that easily mistaken:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:Npn \NoCaseChange #1 { \use:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Add that to your document after loading `biblatex` and it should work fine:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{NFA}{%
  short = NFA,
  short-indefinite = an,
  long = nondeterministic finite automaton,
  long-plural-form = nondeterministic finite automata%
}

\listfiles

%% Workaround to \NoCaseChange and \tl_map_tokens:nn issue:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:Npn \NoCaseChange #1 { \use:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\emph{\Iac{NFA}} is a mathematical machine.
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've updated the code such that we use a string-based test, so the _name_ of the cs has to match, not just the definition: that really should sort things at the cost of a little speed.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you *so* much for your help with this!!  I would have never been able to figure that out! Out of curiosity, do you know which update/install was the trigger for this bug?  Thanks again!!

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for updating the code!  Where can I get the update, or would you recommend I wait until it is picked up by CTAN / TeXLive?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung Out of the three I only follow the updates of `l3kernel`, so I'm not 100% sure, but on [April 3rd](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/commit/187e3b4) `expl3`'s case-changing was added to `acro`, and on [June 6](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/7a3a9d4), `\NoChangeCase` was added to `biblatex`, so a bit later than that (until the CTAN upload).  Joseph sent the `expl3` update to CTAN today, so tomorrow or the day after it should reach the mirrors (depending which you use).  Until then the fix in my answer is enough (safer than a manual update).